# How to use named parameters inside LIKE operator pattern in Adobe Air

Tags: database, sqlite, air, adobe

I wanted to use a named parameter placeholder inside the LIKE operator pattern so that the argument string is properly escaped.

Here's my modified code where I am using the at-param placeholder:

> var stmt = new air.SQLStatement();
>
> stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE title LIKE '%@search%';";
>
> stmt.parameters["@search"] = "argument string";
>
> stmt.execute();

Doing so yields an SQLError with the following details

> message: Error #3315: SQL Error.
>
> details: '@search' parameter name(s) found in parameters property but not in the SQL specified

As suggested by Mike Petty, I tried:

> stmt.text = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE title LIKE "@%search%";';

Which yields to the same SQL Error details.

Documentation has this:

> expr ::= (column-name | expr) LIKE pattern
>
> pattern ::= '[ string | % | _ ]'

My suspicion is that it is skipped due to the qoutes, any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution for this, basically instead of doing it like this:

```
var stmt = new air.SQLStatement();
stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE title LIKE '%@search%';";
stmt.parameters["@search"] = "argument string";
stmt.execute();
```

You have to put a placeholder for the entire LIKE operator pattern and bind the pattern as a parameter.

```
var stmt = new air.SQLStatement();
stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE title LIKE @search;";
stmt.parameters["@search"] = "%" + userInput + "%";
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Remove your :string from your string.

Like works just fine as:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.title LIKE '%string%';
```

Comment: I am sorry if it wasn't clear, it is there for a security reasons

Comment: Well, it definitely works: http://d.pr/i/Pz1I Have you downloaded a sql lite browser/editor. Lita is pretty good. lita: http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58

Comment: Never said that it doesn't work, anyways I have edited my question, maybe it's alot clearer now what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but is your current statement either throwing a SQLError, just doesn't compile, or just doesn't return any results?

If I had to guess I'd say you have a few issues here:

1. You shouldn't have to qualify the column in the where clause since you only have 1 table to select from
2. The parameter *string* is technically a reserved word by AIR / Actionscript (although the case is different) - still a bit confusing.

Even though the documentation and code allow you to use either the colon, or at-symbol, my preference is the @ since it's a bit easier to see ;)

Don't forget to add an itemClass definition of the Class you expect for rows - this helps to avoid anonymous objects.

This should be fairly straight forward:

```
var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.itemClass = Comment;
    stmt.text = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE title LIKE "@%search%";';
    stmt.parameters['@search'] = userInput.text;
    stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onResults);
    stmt.execute();
```

Comment: #1, #2  shouldn't be much of an issue, modified question anyway to avoid confusion

anonymous objects should be fine for now, will look into it later after I find a solution for the SQL error

Thanks!